# How do you create a dialog message box using ASP .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dialog

In WinForms, I can do this:

```
var msg = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "WARNING!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);

if (msg == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //do something
}
```

How do I mimic the above in ASP .NET/C#?

Comment: Usually you don't.  Whenever you would want a popup you more than likely need to just have another regular page.

Comment: take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736720/how-do-you-create-a-dialog-message-box-using-asp-net), it isn't exactly what you are asking for but it can help. In case you want to apply that code, just tell me to give you a hand.

Comment: We could all use a good dialogue box routine....I think this was one of the very first functions I wrote years ago...in Clipper!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't.  The reason is that the code you execute on the server does not directly map to the client.  So you can't create an interactive message box that you can use on the server to get responses from the user.

What you can do is use client-side jquery, and then issue new requests based on their responses.  However, this is not the same as using a MessageBox in WindowsForms as it requires that you let the method finish completely, and then take action based on an entirely new request.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [JQuery Modal Dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/):

Dialog definition:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable">
   <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
      <span id="ui-dialog-title-dialog" class="ui-dialog-title">Dialog title</span>
      <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
   </div>
   <div style="height: 200px; min-height: 109px; width: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="dialog">
      <p>Dialog content goes here.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Dialog opening (just an example):

```
$(foo).dialog({ autoOpen: false })
```

Comment: This is defiantly the best way to go about showing a dialog because the jQuery dialog works in all browsers and it has lots of customization options.

Comment: That doesn't do what the asker wants.  He wants to know how to send a request to the user with a blocking method, and then check the users response in the same method.  That can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can't show a dialog from the server side. You would do this using JavaScript. If you want it styled, I recommend using [jQuery's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [this](http://needim.github.com/noty/) jquery plug-in

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an asp:LinkButton

```
<asp:LinkButton id="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

In code behind:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: return confirm('Are you sure?');");
}

public void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Run code. User already confirmed to get here.
}
```

Comment: I like this...clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using ASP.NET AJAX

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_ConfirmButton.ashx

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example of how to show a dialog message :

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('this is my message :) !');</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the Bootstraps version...I found it was pretty easy to implement and like the added effects.

I have a link button

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete"
          runat="server"
          CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary"
          Visible="true"
          ToolTip="Delete Task"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#DeleteModal">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </asp:LinkButton>
```

And the Delete Modal Div

```
<!-- Delete Modal Begin-->
<div class="modal fade" id="DeleteModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Task</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete task?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"
                    OnClick="btnDelete_Click"
                    CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                    Text="Delete" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Delete Modal End -->
```

[bootstrap modal example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

[bootstrap modal reference](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp)